# Old School Was IE4 and Netscape... Now What?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

Each time i develop a website i got into the first dilemma: what browsers are most used (and what takes a lot of time of developing and not worth to touch), where people see the standards? I got some 300 hits a day sites, but i don't think i can measure it. Anyone has ideas or share the same dilemma with me? A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking which browsers are currently the most popular? The answer would be IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera; in that order.

http://marketshare.hitslink.com/report.aspx?qprid=0&qpcal=1&qptimeframe=M&qpsp=150&qpnp=1

http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php?year=2011&month=7

If you were asking something different I will remove this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out from W3C:
http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

And even more details on Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers

When I develop websites I make sure it validates with W3C standards and looks correct in Firefox, Safari, Chrome and IE7+. Others may think differently though.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate some statistics about who going into your website. Then get from them how many users have Windows/Linux, what users have Trident/Gecko/WebKit.

IE6 support should be break. Nobody likes it, and mostly that's not true that 50% of users use it. 50% is true if we talking about companies where intranet software is written for IE6 and uses ActiveX. Home users now have Firefox, Chrome, Opera. If they use IE, it's probably 7, 8 or 9 now because of Windows Update.